# About proof of fundamental lemma of calculus of variation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I have found several proofs of fundamental lemma of calculus of variation for $C^1$ functions, but could someone help me to show this lemma with the following hypothesis?:

Let be $g:[x,y]\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ a continuous function such that $\int_x^yg(t)h(t)=0$  $\forall{h\in{C^\infty_c(x,y)}}$, show that $g=0$.

Thanks.

Comment: You can look up to Brezis 'Functional analysis..' Lemma IV.2 or Adams 'Sobolev Spaces' Corollary 3.26

Comment: Hello, can you tell me the complete title of the book?

Comment: @mathlife Googling "brezis functional analysis" should give you the rest of the title, as well as an idea of why Matheman didn't want to spell it all out (that title is _long_).

Comment: I have just got the book in my college, but I don't find the proof of this lemma

Answer (score 1):

*Preparation:*

Consider the function
$$
h(x)=\begin{cases} exp\left(\frac1{x^2-1}\right) & |x|<1\\0 & otherwise\end{cases}
$$
Then $h\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$, $h(x)>0$ for $|x|<1$ and $supp(h)=[-1,1]$.

For $x_0\in\mathbb R$ and $\varepsilon>0$ you can consider $h_{x_0,\varepsilon}(x):=h\left(\frac{x-x_0}\varepsilon\right)$.

Then we get $h_{x_0,\varepsilon}\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$, $h_{x_0,\varepsilon}(x)>0$ for $|x-x_0|<\varepsilon$ and $supp(h_{x_0,\varepsilon})=[x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon]$.

*Proof of the lemma:*

Assume $g\not\equiv 0$. Then there exists $x_0\in(x,y)$ such that $g(x_0)\neq 0$. Wlog $g(x_0)>0$. By continuity of $g$, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $g(\xi)>0$ for all $\xi\in[x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon]\subset (x,y)$.

Now, we choose $h_{x_0,\varepsilon}\in C_c^\infty(x,y)$.

We deduce $gh_{x_0,\varepsilon}$ is continuous with $(gh_{x_0,\varepsilon})(\xi)> 0$ for $|\xi-x_0|<\varepsilon$ and $supp(gh_{x_0,\varepsilon})=[x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon]$.

Finally, we conclude
$$
\int_x^y gh_{x_0,\varepsilon}=\int_{x_0-\varepsilon}^{x_0+\varepsilon}\underbrace{gh_{x_0,\varepsilon}}_{\geq 0}\geq \int_{x_0-\frac12\varepsilon}^{x_0+\frac12\varepsilon}\underbrace{gh_{x_0,\varepsilon}}_{> 0}>0.
$$
But this is a contradiction. Hence $g\equiv 0$.

Comment: I don´t see that h is a continuous function, and $h(1)=h(-1)=0$ so the support can't  be $[-1,1]$

Comment: Also, $h(0)=e $

Comment: Check that $x^2-1\nearrow 0$ for $|x|\nearrow 1$. Therefore $\frac1{x^2-1}\to-\infty$ for $|x|\nearrow 1$ and $e^{\frac1{x^2-1}}\to 0$ for $|x|\nearrow 1$. Hence, $h$ is continuous. Further you have to check, that you can argue the same way with all derivatives of $h$ at $\pm 1$. The support is the closure of all points where the function is nonzero. So $supp(h)=cl\{x\in\mathbb R~:~h(x)\neq 0\}=cl (-1,1)=[-1,1]$. Ok, $h(0)=e^{-1}$. There is a mistake, but the explicit value there is not important.

Comment: If $|x|\rightarrow{1}$ then $x^2-1\rightarrow{0}$ and $\frac{1}{e^{x^2-1}}\rightarrow{1}$ because $1/e^0$ is 1

Comment: I see your misunderstanding. You have to read $e^{\frac1{x^2-1}}$ as $exp\left(\frac1{x^2-1}\right)$ not as $\frac1{exp(x^2-1)}$... ok. I rewrite it to make it more clear.